# How to select the content within brackets including brackets and without including brackets?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, delimiter-matching

I have some code structure e.g

```
{
  {
    // Some content goes here
  }
  [
    // Some content goes here
  ]
}
```

I want to select the content inside `{ }` in some case and also content inside with opening and closing brackets included in some case.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use text objects to accomplish this. Start a selection with `v` and then:

For selecting inside use: `i{`

For selecting the whole block including braces use: `a{`

You can also do this with any type of parenthesis by changing `{` to `[` or whatever. It's worth taking a little time to learn text objects as they make vim a lot more powerful!

See `:h text-objects` for more info.